# what is adc_timer

Tags: ros, arduino, rosserial, tutorial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the rosserial_arduino oscilloscope example there is the following line:
long adc_timer;

does anyone know what adc_timer is or how it's being used?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38703/what-is-adc_timer/) by [magdes](https://answers.ros.org/users/2830/magdes/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-07-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I've done this tutorial as well, and I don't see any use for that line in the code. I am certain if you comment it out (go ahead and try) that it will compile just fine.

The best reason I could see for something like this is to put a timestamp on the message, but you don't need a separate variable to keep track of that value, since you can simply use the nodehandle timestamp call : nh.now();

If you're interesting in adding a time stamp, you want to modify your message with a header. I had written up a similar thing on my blog that outputs the oscilloscope/ADC values in volts instead of counts, and includes the time stamp. If you're interested you can check it out here :
[Custom ROS Messages with rosserial_arduino](http://dougsbots.blogspot.com/2012/06/custom-ros-messages-with.html).

Regards,
Doug

---

Originally posted by [dougbot01](https://answers.ros.org/users/2842/dougbot01/) with karma: 342 on 2012-07-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2